# Solve $abxcd = y$ for $x$ in a group.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Solve $abxcd = y$ for $x$ in a group.

I just used the inverses of a,b,c,d and multiplying on both sides to get $x = b^{-1}a^{-1}yd^{-1}c^{-1}$

is this correct , or close to it? If not, whats wrong and how is it fixed.

Comment: seems fine to me, doubt you can do any better without extra information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's fine. One way to check this, using associativity and the fact that the multiplying by the identity doesn't change anything, is to compute
\begin{align*}
ab(b^{-1} a^{-1} y d^{-1} c^{-1}) cd &= abb^{-1} a^{-1} y d^{-1} c^{-1} cd \\
&= aa^{-1} y d^{-1} d \\
&= y
\end{align*}

Comment: very helpful thanks.